# How can I improve my picture proof of Reverse Triangle Inequality?

Tags: visualization, triangle-inequality

Diagram beneath reappears on standardized tests IN BLACK AND WHITE ***with different lengths, letters,  and orientation*** that require students to label in terms of $\vec{b}, \vec{r}$ ( = circle's radius ) the:

1. long line from $(-4, 0)$ to B.
2. short line segment from a point on the circumference to B.

[image]

So I added color.

[image]

##### But many parents and students STILL  fail to distinguish $\color{deepskyblue}{|\vec{b}| - |\vec{r}|}$  from   $\color{red}{\vec{b} - \vec{r}}$, solely by eye! How can I improve my diagram? How can I better contrast the differences between  $\color{cornflowerblue}{|\vec{b}| - |\vec{r}|}$ vs. $\color{red}{\vec{b} - \vec{r}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people may never be convinced.  But I would have thought this might help others:

- $\vec{r}$ is the vector $OR$ and $R$ is $|\vec{r}|$ from $O$
- $\vec{b}$ is the vector $OB$ and $B$ is $|\vec{b}|$ from $O$
- So $RB$ is $\vec{b}-\vec{r}$ and $B$ is $|\vec{b}-\vec{r}|$ from $R$
- The black circle about $O$ containing $R$ is of radius $|\vec{r}|$
- The point $D$ is where the black circle crosses $OB$ and is $|\vec{r}|$ from $O$ so $|\vec{b}|-|\vec{r}|$ from $B$.
- The red circle about $B$ containing $R$ is of radius $|\vec{b}-\vec{r}|$  and the red radius $RB$ shown is $\vec{b}-\vec{r}$
- The blue circle about $B$ containing $D$ is of radius $|\vec{b}|-|\vec{r}|$ and the blue radius $DB$ shown is of length $|\vec{b}-\vec{r}|$
- $D$ is the closest point on the black circle to $B$
- So $|\vec{b}|-|\vec{r}| \le |\vec{b}-\vec{r}|$
- with equality when $D$ is $R$, i.e when $R$ lies on $OB$

[image]

This is not a complete proof, and in particular does not deal with the case where  $|\vec{b}|<|\vec{r}|$.

Another diagram may help for that, and shows that we need more absolute signs in the argument above.  The key point is that $D$ remains the closest point on the black circle to $B$ but better to say $D$ is $\Big||\vec{b}|-|\vec{r}|\Big|$ from $B$ and so $\Big||\vec{b}|-|\vec{r}|\Big| \le |\vec{b}-\vec{r}|$, with equality $D$ is $R$ i.e. when $R$ lies on the ray $\vec{OB}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you complete this proof? Kindly deal with the case where $|\vec{b}|<|\vec{r}|$?

Comment: @Scexit I have added a second picture and a few words